# Is there a way to repeat a nUnit TestFixture multiple times?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

Is there a way to run a nunit TestFixture once for each item in a list? Let's say I have a setup something like the following:

```
Public Class TestData
{
Public String Parameter1{get;}
Public String Parameter2{get;}
Public String Parameter3{Get;}
}
```

What I would like to do is create a list of TestData objects:

```
List<TestData> inputs = new List<TestData>(){};
```

And then using nunit 3, run a TestFixture and all Tests housed within it against each item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TestFixtureAttribute` may take a list of arguments, similar to the `TestCaseAttribute`. The values provided are used as arguments to the constructor of the test class. The usual process is to save the constructor arguments in a member variable. For example:

```
[TestFixture(123, "John")]
[TestFixture(456, "Mary")]
[TestFixture(789, "Fred")]
public class MyTest
{
    private int _num;
    private string _name;

    public MyTest(int num, string name)
    {
        _num = num;
        _name = name;
    }

    ...
}
```

The fixture will be created and executed three times, once for each set of arguments. You may use the saved values in your tests, which may be simple tests or parameterized tests.

As with `[TestCase]`, you are limited to constant arguments of the types permitted by the C# languge.

If you don't like that limitation and/or have a lot of test cases and prefer to consolidate the data, you can replace all the `[TestFixture]` entries by a single `[TestFixtureSource]`, like this...

```
[TestFixtureSource(nameof(MyTestData))]
public class MyTest
{
    private int _num;
    private string _name;

    public MyTest(int num, string name)
    {
        _num = num;
        _name = name;
    }

    ...

    static IEnumerable<TestFixtureData> MyTestData()
    {
        yield return new TestFixtureData(123, "John");
        yield return new TestFixtureData(456, "Mary");
        yield return new TestFixtureData(789, "Fred");
    }
}
```

This attribute is a bit more complicated than `[TestCase]` so be sure to read the [documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testfixturesource.html). In particular, check out "Form 2" if you want to share the same data among multiple fixture classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Charlie. I was hoping for something similar to how [TestCaseSource] works, where by I could provide it an object type of a class which contains my parameters, and a method which generates an IEnumerable<TestData>, and the fixture could be ran for each object that yields out. If that's not possible, and I want to run a Fixture 20-30 times, is there a better solution than to write 30 different static Fixture attribute declarations at the top of my class?

Comment: Yes, there is. I was intending to add that to my answer but I got distracted by something else and forgot to come back. I'll do an update now.